# Extracting certain text in python BS4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract certain text in BS4. Sample HTML below.

```html
</tr><tr id="_Gonzaga" class="seedrow">
<td title="Click to show/hide ranks" class='lowrowclick' style="text-align:center;font-size:8px">2</td>
<td  id='Gonzaga' class="teamname"><a href="team.php?team=Gonzaga&year=2019" style="text-decoration: none;">Gonzaga<span class="lowrow" style="font-size:10px"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 seed, <span style='background-color:#BAE2C6'>Elite Eight</span></span></a></td>
```

current code is:

```
data = soup.findAll('tr', attrs={"class": "seedrow"})
team_name = item.find('td', class_ = 'teamname')
team_id = team_name.find('a').contents[0]
seed = team_name.find('span').text
print(team_id, seed)
```

This returns:

```
Gonzaga, '\xa0\xa0\xa01 seed, Elite Eight'
```

What I want:

```
Gonzaga, 1 seed, Elite Eight
```

Comment: If you don't like the `\xa0`, you can `.strip('\xa0')`, or `.replace('\xa0', ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to extract 3 separated strings. You can use `.get_text()` with custom `separator=` character and then split on this character:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<tr id="_Gonzaga" class="seedrow">
<td title="Click to show/hide ranks" class='lowrowclick' style="text-align:center;font-size:8px">2</td>
<td  id='Gonzaga' class="teamname"><a href="team.php?team=Gonzaga&year=2019" style="text-decoration: none;">Gonzaga<span class="lowrow" style="font-size:10px"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 seed, <span style='background-color:#BAE2C6'>Elite Eight</span></span></a></td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll('tr', attrs={"class": "seedrow"})

for item in data:
    team_name = item.find('td', class_ = 'teamname')

    a, b, c = team_name.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')

    print(a)
    print(b.strip(','))
    print(c)
```

Prints:

```
Gonzaga
1 seed
Elite Eight
```